# ACF Repeater field doesn't show up

Tags: php, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I’ve got a problem with the repeater field that doesn’t show up in this page and i don’t understand why. When i call normal field it works, here is my code :

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 6,'category_name' => 'une')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('evenement') ): while ( have_rows('evenement') ) : the_row(); ?>
<?php the_sub_field('date_debut_evenement');?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for your help !

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Please add post id when you count acf rows:

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 6,'category_name' => 'une')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('evenement','$postID') ): while ( have_rows('evenement','$postID') ) : the_row(); ?>
<?php the_sub_field('date_debut_evenement');?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i try your solution but I found another one !

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, i change the query with this and it seems to work fine :

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'showposts' => 6,
'category_name' => 'une',
'post_type'=> array('post','spectacles','photos','videos')
) );
?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
```